# How the empty line gives an error in JavaScript (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

Tags: javascript

I have this error in javascript code :
(JavaScript error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input))
I saw many questions same as this, but could not solve my error, so now ask help
My code is so simple as follows;

```
const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play')
const audio = new Audio('/sounds/1M.mp4')

function playAudio(){
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        audio.play();
        audio.loop = true;
        audio.playbackRate = 2;
}

playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    playAudio()
})
```

Why this kind of error comes out from my code?
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input) : audio.js 14 (line 14 is the empty line next the end of parenthesis '})'
How  the empty line gives an error ?

Comment: Your code doesn't close your function body, notice that your `for()` loop is closed by line 9, not your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the for loop

```
const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play')
const audio = new Audio('/sounds/1M.mp4')

    function playAudio(){
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            audio.play();
            audio.loop = true;
            audio.playbackRate = 2;
        }
    }
    playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        playAudio()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you forgot to close the `playAudio` function when defining it. You can fix it like this:

```js
const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play')
const audio = new Audio('/sounds/1M.mp4')

function playAudio() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    audio.play();
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.playbackRate = 2;
  } // <---
}

playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playAudio();
});
```